# Is there a way to open a cloned git project in Xcode done using Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm collaborating with fellow students on a group project for the first time, and we are using github for version control.  The project was done in Visual Studio, and I have git cloned it onto my computer.  I would like to open the project in Xcode so I can work on it but I'm not sure how or if I even can.

Comment: What's stopping you? Did you try? Most editors support opening files to edit  perhaps you cannot open it as "a project", but you can always open and edit individual files (with *any* editor).

Comment: XCode and Visual Studio will not share the same project file. If you want that you wil have to use something like CMake.

Comment: Yeah so I've just created my own project and added the hpp/cpp files over to work on.  Guess I was overthinking it :)